# Connect to Parse.com as a data source for analytics

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform

Can anybody tell me how i connect to Parse.com in order to use it as a data source for some analytics software i'm using?

As far as i'm aware Parse.com uses MongoDB as its backend. I can chose MongoDB as the data sourse in my analytics software, but it wants a URL in this format:

```
mongodb://hostname:27017/database
```

Does anybody know how i can connect to Parse.com using this method? I certainly don't see anything in the Parse.com docs that tell me how to connect in this fashion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Parse is not a database you can access directly. They provide you the storage and an API to read/write the data but never direct access to the underlying database.